# Winston - log rotation order while useing maxsize

Tags: node.js, centos, winston

I'm using Winston with maxsize as the rotation strategy, after the file (application.log) size have reached to the maxsize the rotation is working as expected and starting to write to a second file (application2.log)

My problem is that the current write is always done to the latest file (application2.log) and not to the original file (application.log) and once it reached again to the maxsize value truncate the content to a rotated file (application3.log).
Is it a Winston configuration or that it should be done on the OS level (in my case CentOS)?

Answer (score 0):

turns out Winston has a tailable option to allow constant writing to the log file head